# How to check if one of the edit text is empty

Tags: java, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have 2 edit texts how to check if one of the edit text is empty currently what I'm doing is

```
if(tvPhoneNumber.getText().toString().matches("")){
                if(tvContryCode.getText().length() == 0){
                    //show error
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else{
                    phoneNumber = tvPhoneNumber.getText().toString();
                    profile.put("phone_number", selectedCountryDialCode.concat(phoneNumber));
                }}else{
                profile.put("phone_number", selectedCountryDialCode.concat(phoneNumber));
            }
```

Comment: use condition1 || condition2 ?

Comment: could you write answer?

Comment: Just list the mandatory field an manage them in one method like `EditText[] mandatory = { edit1, edit2 }; for each ( edit : mandatory){ not empty(edit);}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(tvContryCode.getText().isEmpty() || tvPhoneNumber.getText().isEmpty()){
  // one of the two is empty
}
```

**Edit 1:**
or if you want to know wich one is empty

```
if(tvContryCode.getText().isEmpty()){
  // tvContryCode is empty
}
else if(tvPhoneNumber.getText().isEmpty()){
  // tvPhoneNumber is empty
}
// Edit 2:
else{
  // none of the textviews is empty
}
```

**Edit 3:**

```
if(tvContryCode.getText().isEmpty() && tvPhoneNumber.getText().isEmpty()){
  // Both of the tv´s are empty
}
```

Comment: what about if tvCountry code is not empty will it evaluate the other statement?

Comment: In edit of your question, if both are not empty then

Comment: what do you say when we apply && and || operators

Comment: @blackHawk How do you mean? && is AND where both conditions should be true. || is OR where one of them should be true.

Comment: then can we apply && operator in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether a String is empty or not using the method `String.isEmpty()`.

**Note:** This method does not check if the String is null.

Comment: what about making condition if one of the two edit text is empty

Answer (score 0):

You can use [apache lang3 library](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html). It will check **empty, null or whitespace**.

```
if(StringUtils.isBlank(tvContryCode.getText()) ){
}

if(StringUtils.isBlank(tvPhoneNumber.getText())){          
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `TextUtils.isEmpty()` method

```
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(tvPhoneNumber.getText().toString())) {
    ...
} else {
    profile.put("phone_number", selectedCountryDialCode.concat(phoneNumber));
}
```